# Routes don't work in production of react website

Tags: reactjs

I have a question.
I created a react website and everything works perfectly on local development.
So if I go to localhost:8080/about I get on the about page.

When I build the website only an index.html gets made.
When I navigate the website from the index page, it all works, also the urls changes to /about when I go to the about page through the menu.
But when I go to [www.website.com/about](http://www.website.com/about) by typing in the address I get an error page.

Who can help me with this?

JayD

Comment: Where are you deploying it at ?

Comment: have you created a page with this route?

Comment: Please share the part of the code where you have routed/called this

Comment: @DevGuy I have my own server at Strato.de

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani Yes, and on local development everything works just fine

Comment: @mw509

`
<Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ Dashboard } />
        <Route exact path='/about' component={ About } />
</Switch>
`

Comment: Its not about code, its about server in my opinion. I had similiar issue with S3 bucket when ive landed on homepage and click links everything was working, and if i write link directly wouldnt work saying forbidden access.

Comment: @DevGuy That seems the problem, how did you fixed this?

Comment: Using url rewrite .and redirect. But ive forgot exactly as it was long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your react router accordingly. Usually you need to add one extra file in your build files. Below is the tutorial on how to setup react router using fierbase and netlify. If you deploy somewhere else, please let me know. I can help you with that.

[Firebase](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-firebase-router)

[Netlify](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-to-netlify-363b8a98a985/)

Comment: I have my own server at Strato.de

Comment: @JayD i think this tutorial will help you https://medium.com/@aforamitrai/how-to-deploy-react-app-on-shared-hosting-cpanel-d682b0342424

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me with my problem.